# How to move modifications in Napili template to production?

Tags: community, deployment, napili

I have modified some changes in both lightning components and a community site which is built on Napili template in the sandbox. How can I move the changes from sandbox to production, Is it possible to do with change sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you can find the list of available components to push through a change set here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm&type=0